# Gpg4win download integrity check

Tags: windows-8, pgp, certutil

I just downloaded `gpg4win` onto Windows 8.

I wanted to check the integrity, and apparently you can do so with `certutil`. So I navigated to my downloads folder and typed:

```
C:\Users\xxx\Downloads> certutil -hashfile gpg4win-3.0.2.exe sha1
SHA1 hash of file gpg4win-3.0.2.exe:
a2 da ba f0 a6 5f 3e f3 0c 60 e7 52 2f 34 59 c8 11 20 09 8e
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
```

But, when I go to https://www.gpg4win.org/package-integrity.html,
they display a bunch of text and even the line:

```
sha1_fpr: DE:16:D5:97:2F:0B:73:95:F7:D9:1E:DC:1F:21:9B:0F:FE:89:FA:B3
```

Doesn't agree with what `certutil` spat out. So my question is:

1. Have I even used `certutil` correctly?, meaning the sha1 truly doesn't check out... and I should re-download the file from somewhere else, or
2. Have I mis-used `certutil` / completely misunderstood the integrity
   checking process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did it correctly.

Scroll down a bit more and you will see

```
a2dabaf0a65f3ef30c60e7522f3459c81120098e  gpg4win-3.0.2.exe
```

Which is the same hash you got, but without the spacing.

The

```
sha1_fpr: DE:16:D5:97:2F:0B:73:95:F7:D9:1E:DC:1F:21:9B:0F:FE:89:FA:B3
```

you see is the SHA1 fingerprint (FPR) for the code signing certificate

Comment: thank you so much!!! I guess I didn't scroll down cos I thought all the information was at the top. I have no idea what a fingerprint  / FPR "for code signing certificate" is... another new thing to learn :)